# Is Distribution Upgrade bad for server?

Tags: server, apt, upgrade

The version of Ubuntu offered in VPS is usually old, and I need newer version of application. Thus, I should upgrade the ubuntu version.

However, `apt-get dist-upgrade` is not 100% safe (this is probably the reason that it is always recommended to take backup before this action). In desktop, any problem in upgrade or packages can be easily noticed, but in server, it can be hidden. Not visible to the admin, but affecting the experience of end-users (e.g., website visitors).

Is it safe to upgrade the ubuntu distribution in a VPS?

Answer (score 2):

> (this is probably the reason that it is always recommended to take backup before this action)

No, -any- update, upgrade or any change to a system can kill it. So at -any- given point where you want to update, upgrade or make changes to a system you make a backup. Maintaining a system is about doing things with the least amount of risks. The big problem with servers is that others depend on it so messing up is more of a problem then when changing a desktop but even for a desktop the 1st comment needs to be: create a backup or prepare to have to deal with loss of data. If only that you can never predict a power outage.

> Is it safe to upgrade the ubuntu distribution in a VPS?

Depends. In general it will be safe but your system will be different than someone elses. Maybe you have some exotic software installed that is distribution specific or does no longer have a maintainer and does not work on the new system. Unlikely but it can happen. We used to have a piece of software called doublevision (kind of like a "screen" alternative) that checks on the 3rd digit of the kernel if it is still valid and refuses to run. Payware so upgrading means paying a fee to have it working again  ...

We have 3 servers in a datacenter. 1 is the one we store backups on. 1 is the active one. The 3rd one has identical software and data (mysql replication for instance) as the 2nd one and is the one that is being updated. After the update the 3rd one will become the active one and the 2nd one is updated. As I said above: we try to do update, upgrades with zero risk.

Answer (score 2):

> However, apt-get dist-upgrade is not 100% safe (this is probably the reason that it is always recommended to take backup before this action).

If you are talking about upgrading between version, I've seen that the `do-release-upgrade` is less error prone in this cases.

> In desktop, any problem in upgrade or packages can be easily noticed, but in server, it can be hidden. Not visible to the admin, but affecting the experience of end-users (e.g., website visitors).

Sometimes is better to test the server in a virtualized environment, then deploy the virtualized image in the server for a "clean upgrade". That way you can test all you want before affecting the end users.

> Is it safe to upgrade the ubuntu distribution in a VPS?

Define "safe". Any change, small or big, in any environment has a risk. The way you deal with this "risk" will determinate the "safeness" of the operation.

> Is Distribution Upgrade bad for server?

Depends what you like and/or seek. Is always recommended having latest versions (with backports) in server-like systems, due obvious and reused reasons. Again, upgrading always has a risk of something going wire, if you like you can create a clon image of the system, upgrade it, test it, then replace the production server with the clon image.

There are several ways you can do this, but is good as always have a backup plan to reduce down time.